# Is the Riemann integral of a strictly positive function positive?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

In the proof [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210421152213/https://projecteuclid.org/DPubS/Repository/1.0/Disseminate?view=body&id=pdf_1&handle=euclid.bams/1183510788) a strictly positive function in $(0,\pi)$ is integrated over this interval and the integral is claimed as a positive number. It seems intuitively obvious as the area enclosed by a continuous function's graph lying entirely above the x-axis and the x-axis should not be zero. But how can I prove this formally?

If the function is positive over a closed interval apparently [the result is not true](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=clhY9O__t6QC&pg=PA147&lpg=PA147&dq=riemann%20integral%20of%20a%20strictly%20positive%20function%20is%20positive&source=bl&ots=ALdNKiLZ6y&sig=cdXCvCM8v71jMj0jkWHv7JidXv8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=r5BdUbv0G8qUrgeqqYHgCg#v=onepage&q=riemann%20integral%20of%20a%20strictly%20positive%20function%20is%20positive&f=false) (link goes to page 147 in *Theories of Integration* by Kurtz and Swarz). This has further confused me. Can someone please clarify my doubt.

Thanks

Comment: If you have a counterexample function $f$ s.t. $f(x)>0$ on the closed interval $[a,b]$ but $\int_a^b f = 0$, then clearly $f(x)>0$ on $(a,b)$ and $\int_a^b f = 0$.

Comment: Any graph argument implicitly assumes that the function is continuous. In which case $f>0$ implies $\int_a^b f>0$.

Comment: to add to a comment by @julien, although Riemann integrability does  not require continuity, the function in your first link is continuous

Comment: If $f$ is Riemann integrable, then $f$ is continuous a.e., and one just needs continuity at a single point to show $\int_a^b f > 0$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $f : I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function on some interval $I$.

If $f$ is continuous and positive on $I$, then $\displaystyle \int_I f >0$. Indeed, $f \geq \alpha >0$ on some closed interval $K \subset I$, so $\displaystyle \int_I f \geq \int_K f \geq \alpha \cdot \mu(K)>0$.

Comment: @julien But Riemann integrable $\implies$ Lebesgue integrable, hence how could a counterexample exist?

Comment: A Riemann integrable function $f$ over a nondegenerate interval has points of continuity. This is enough to insure the integral is positive for positive $f$.

Comment: @DavidMitra   I was impressed by Remark 4.21 [here](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=clhY9O__t6QC&pg=PA147&lpg=PA147&dq=riemann%20integral%20of%20a%20strictly%20positive%20function%20is%20positive&source=bl&ots=ALdNKiLZ6y&sig=cdXCvCM8v71jMj0jkWHv7JidXv8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=r5BdUbv0G8qUrgeqqYHgCg&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=riemann%20integral%20of%20a%20strictly%20positive%20function%20is%20positive&f=false). And I did not really think about it any further...

Comment: @Did Sure, I was silly. Do you have any idea of what they mean [here](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=clhY9O__t6QC&pg=PA147&lpg=PA147&dq=riemann%20integral%20of%20a%20strictly%20positive%20function%20is%20positive&source=bl&ots=ALdNKiLZ6y&sig=cdXCvCM8v71jMj0jkWHv7JidXv8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=r5BdUbv0G8qUrgeqqYHgCg&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=riemann%20integral%20of%20a%20strictly%20positive%20function%20is%20positive&f=false) in Remark 4.21?

Comment: @julien: I can only imagine that they mean with the machinery developed so far, they cannot prove it. However, I think it is straightforward to prove, let me see if I can dig up a proof.

Comment: @julien "from our results **so far**".

Comment: @Did Oh, boy, I'm having a bad day. Thanks.

Comment: @julien: I suffer from chronic 'hypothesis insecurity', so can't survive mathematically  far from my library :-).

Comment: @Seirios: Can we not say "every closed interval" instead of "any closed interval"?

Comment: @Shahab: Yes, it works for all closed interval $K \subset I$.

Answer (score 25):

Here is a "direct" proof that does not require knowledge of the continuity properties of Riemann-integrable functions:

- Suppose by way of contradiction that $\int_0^1 f = 0$.
- It follows that the upper Darboux sums can be made arbitrarily small.  Choose some partition $\mathcal{P}_1$ such that $U(f; \mathcal{P}_1) < 1$.
- There must be some subinterval $I_1$ of $\mathcal{P}_1$ on which the supremum of $f$ is less than 1, as otherwise, summing over all subintervals contradicts the condition that $U(f; \mathcal{P}_1)< 1$.
- Choose some partition $\mathcal{P}_2$ for which $U(f; \mathcal{P}_2) < \frac{|I_1|}{2}$.  We may assume WLOG that $\mathcal{P}_2$ is a refinement of $\mathcal{P}_1$, as otherwise re replace $\mathcal{P}_2$ by their common refinement.
- Of the subintervals of $I_1$ which are in $\mathcal{P}_2$, their must be one, which we call $I_2$, on which the supremum of $f$ is less than $\frac{1}{2}$.  If not, the sum of $M_k \Delta x_k$ over the subintervals of $I_1$ would yield at least $\frac{|I_1|}{2}$, and $U(f; \mathcal{P}_2)$ would be at least this much.
- Similarly, choose $\mathcal{P}_3$ a refinement of $\mathcal{P}_2$ with the property $U(f; \mathcal{P}_3) < \frac{|I_2|}{3}$.
- Continuing in this manner, we obtain a nested sequence $I_1 \supseteq I_2 \supseteq \dots$ of closed bounded intervals with the property that $f(x) < \frac{1}{n}$ for all $x \in I_n$.
- By the Nested Interval Property, the intersection $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n$ is nonempty.  But any point $x$ in this intersection must have the property $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: f(x) < \frac{1}{n}$, which implies $f(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 11):

If $f$ is non-negative, Riemann integrable and $\int_a^b f(x) dx = 0$ (with $a<b$) then it must be the case that $f(x) = 0$ a.e. Hence if $f$ is strictly positive on $[a,b]$, then it must be the case that $\int_a^b f(x) dx > 0$.

This is straightforward to see using the Lebesgue integral.

See Corollary 3 in [www.math.sc.edu/~schep/riemann.pdf](http://www.math.sc.edu/~schep/riemann.pdf) for a straightforward proof. The essence is to show that  for all $c > 0$ the set $\{x \in [a, b] | f (x) \ge c \}$ has content zero.