# Integral of a positive function is positive?

Tags: calculus, integration

**Question:**
Let $f:[a.b]\to \Bbb R \in R[a,b]$ s.t. $f(x)>0 \  
\forall x \in \Bbb R.$ Is $\int _a^b f(x)\,dx>0$ ?

**What We thought:**
We know how to prove it for weak inequality, for strong inequality - no clue :-)

Comment: @ user: Hi what is the notation R[a,b] standing for ? Regards

Comment: R[a,b] means Riemann integrable in [a,b]

Comment: Do you know measure theory?

Comment: only calculus I, now starting calc 2.

Comment: @user1685224: In your definition of Riemann integrable, do you require the function $f(x)$ to be continuous?

Comment: Smells false. Try $a=b$.

Comment: no we don't require it to be continuous. And we've been told that the statement is true. But we cannot figure it out. And also $a\ne b$ of course.

Comment: $f$ is Riemann integrable iff $f$ is continuous almost everywhere.

Comment: Review https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351157/is-the-riemann-integral-of-a-strictly-positive-function-positive

Comment: [Show that the integral of a positive function is positive](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1693153/721644) and [Integral of a positive function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2003104/721644)

Answer (score 3):

This is a surprisingly rough question! I don't think there's any easy way around using (or proving as part of the solution) that every Riemann integrable function on $(a,b)$ is continuous at at least one point. You can show this fairly easily using e.g. Darboux sums, but I would consider this beyond the scope of an introductory Calculus class... maybe another answer can fill in how one might easily see this?

In any case, let's say that $f$ is continuous at some point $p\in (a,b)$, with $f(p) = k > 0$. This means that there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(p+h) - k| < \frac{k}{2}$ for $|h| < \delta$. Let $L = \min(\delta, p-a, b-p) > 0$. Then
$$\int_a^b f(x)\, dx \geq \int_{p-L}^{p+L} f(x)\, dx \geq \ldots$$
can you take it from there?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, We did learn lower and upper Darboux sums, we thought maybe using reductio ad absurdum of I=0... By using these things do you think it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

If f is continuous, we can argue like this, Let $m$ be the infemum of the function on$[a,b]$. show that $m \gt 0$ and $\int _a^b f(x)\,dx \gt m(b-a) \gt 0$

Comment: $f$ is not necessarily continuous, so the infemum could well be zero.

Comment: @user7530, ya. sorry. I have changed my answer.