# How to prove that the integral of a positive, continuous function is positive?

Tags: integration

Obviously intuitively the area under something that is above the x-axis is always positive, but how can I show this with a proof?

Comment: This is very likely a duplicate.

Comment: I've been searching and so far everything involved proving something is continuous based on the fact that it's Riemann integrable, which I don't need since I already know it's continuous.

Comment: Write down a lower Riemann sum. Show that such a sum is always positive. Hence the Riemann integral, which is greater than or equal to that lower sum must also be positive.

Comment: Duplicates: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/553031/472818

Answer (score 1):

Choose a point $x$ at which $f(x) > 0$.  Let $\epsilon = f(x)/2$. Choose $\delta > 0$ so that $|t - x| < \delta\implies f(x) > \epsilon.$  Can you do the rest?

Comment: I suppose you mean $f(t)>\epsilon$.