# Property of Antiderivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Consider two differentiable functions $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $g:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$. Suppose that there exists a $\delta$ such that for $x>\delta$, $f'(x)>g'(x)$. I am trying to show that this implies there exists a $\delta_2$ such that for $x>\delta_2$, $f(x)>g(x)$. So far, I have used $f(x)=\int_{\delta}^x f'(t)dt + f(\delta)$ and similarly for $g(x)$ to show that this obviously holds if $f(\delta)>g(\delta)$. I am now trying to construct the case where $f(\delta)<g(\delta)$.

Comment: I don't think this is true without some assumption like $f(0)=g(0)$

Comment: how would this assumption help?

Comment: Consider the difference $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$. (Equivalently, assume $g=0$.)

Comment: [Integral of positive function is positive](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/553031/472818)

Comment: It is obvious the conclusion does not hold: there are strictly increasing functions which are negative, for example: $\arctan x-(\pi/2)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $f(x) = -2e^{-x},$ and $g(x) = 1-e^{-x}$

Then $f(x) < g(x)$ for all $x$ and $f'(x) > g'(x)$ for all $x.$

Comment: @AryamanMaithani thanks, I have made a fix.  I think this holds.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a long comment than an answer, but I wanted to make two points

1. Expanding on @RyszardSzwarc comment if it wasn't clear: let $f(x)=\arctan(x)-\pi/2$ and $g(x)=0$. Then $f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is strictly greater than $g'(x)=0$ for all $x$, but $f(x)<g(x)$ for all $x$.
2. Suppose now that $f'(x)>g'(x)$ for all $x$ and $f(0)=g(0)$. Then $f(x)>g(x)$ for all $x>0$ since
   \begin{align}
   f(x)&=f(x)-0\\
   &=f(x)-g(x)\\
   &=f(0)+\int_0^x f'(t)dt-\left(g(0)+\int_0^x g'(t) dt\right) \\
   &=f(0)-g(0)+\int_0^x\left(f'(t)-g'(t)\right)dt\\
   &\int_0^x\left(f'(t)-g'(t)\right)dt.
   \end{align}
   Then you need the surprisingly non-trivial fact that [the integral of a positive function is positive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553031/integral-of-a-positive-function-is-positive). It is true that integrable functions are continuous almost everywhere, and once you know $f'(x)-g'(x)$ is continuous at some point, it's [relatively easy to show](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124311/how-to-prove-that-the-integral-of-a-positive-continuous-function-is-positive?noredirect=1&lq=1) $\int_0^x\left(f'(t)-g'(t)\right)>0$ for all $x>0$.