# If a function is strictly positive is the riemann integral strictly positive?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that f : [0, 1] −→ (0, ∞) is a Riemann-integrable function.
Prove that the integral is strictly positive.

Here is my thought process:

The function is riemann integral implies that the set of discontiuties has measure zero. Assume that f is contiuous at some c in [0,1] This implies that there exists some r,z such that f>=r on [c-z,c+z] 
which implies (????) that the integral on [0,1] is bigger than the integral on  [c-z,c+z] is bigger than or equal to 2zr, which is positive.

I am not sure if I am making any assumptions here that I can't make, especially where I marked with (????)

Comment: I would think that you could appeal to partitions, and take a simple one or two element partition and show that the lower bound must be positive and therefore the integral must be positive.

Comment: I find your reasoning correct.  You need to pick $r>0$, and you need to note that the integral on the rest of $[0,1]$ besides $[c-z,c+z]$ is nonnegative and so can't cancel the positive value of the integral on $[c-z,c+z]$.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351157/is-the-riemann-integral-of-a-strictly-positive-function-positive

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange, I'd recommend you the page http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for future reference. It will make your question much more easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is nonnegative and has $0$ integral, it must be $0$ a.e., but it isn't, so the integral must be greater than $0$.