# Example for equality of Integral.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, riemann-integration

Let $f,g$ be bounded real valued function defined on $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$. My source says that:

> Suppose that $f(x)< g(x)$ for all $x\in [a,b]$ and $f,g$ are Riemann Integrable on $[a,b]$.
>
> Then $\int_a^b f \leq \int_a^b g$.

I do not understand why $\le$ is used instead of $<$.

Is this meant to imply that the equality case exists? If so, could you provide an example?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where exactly do you see that statement?

Comment: See this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351157/is-the-riemann-integral-of-a-strictly-positive-function-positive  The idea is that if $f\leq  g$ and the integrals are equal then the set $\{f<g\}$ has Lebesgue measure zero. If the inequality is strict everywhere then the integral inequality is also strict.

Comment: @KennyLau In calculus book.

Comment: @Planche as stated the result is true, if not as precise as possible. Sometimes that is the expense of a simpler proof. Or it could just be sloppy editing.

Comment: But a simpler proof can be found for a stronger result, namely just assume $f\le g.$