# Inequality in Riemann Integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

We already know that if $f(x)\le g(x)$ for $x\in[a,b]$, then $\int_a^b f(x)dx\le \int_a^b g(x)dx.$

Can we have example of $f$ and $g$ such that $f(x)<g(x)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$, but $\int_a^b f(x) dx=\int_a^b g(x) dx$?

Comment: Yes , If youTake a=b

Comment: Smart answer, hehehehehe. What if a<b?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351157/is-the-riemann-integral-of-a-strictly-positive-function-positive

Comment: ZeroToZero I think if a<b it will not possible atleast in $\Bbb R^1$. But if we consider the Extended Real Number space it might be possible. But I'm not sure whether we can consider the Extended Real Number space as such .

Comment: Thank you @Clement C, so:
 "If a function is strictly positive, then the integral is always strictly positive", 
but it still haven't answered, the possibility whether the integral could be 0, I think?

Comment: Thank you for the remark @Debjit Mullick. Yes, I am just considering the real $\mathbb{R}$, not the extended real one.

Comment: @ZeroToZero This says that if $h(x) > 0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$, then $\int_a^b h(x) dx >0$. This answers your question, by using $h=g-f>0$ (saying we cannot have an example like the one you want).