For a function $f> 0$, does $\int_a^b f dx=0$ imply that $a=b$?
I know that  $\int_{a}^{a} f \,dx = 0  $.
If $f([a,b]) \subseteq (0, \infty)$ , and $\int_{a}^{b} f \,dx = 0 $ then does it implies that $a=b $ ?
If so then how can i prove it ?
If not what else can  we say about this integral and integrand ?
please improve my question if it has any mistakes.

What do you mean when you write that $f>0$?

The integral of a positive function over a non-degenerate interval is always positive, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/351157/42969. Unless I am mistaken, this is true for both Riemann and Lebesgue integrals.

i mean range of f is positive real numbers.@JoséCarlosSantos

@MartinR Yes, even though the link you gave seems to have solutions only for Riemann integrable functions -- for the case of Lebesgue measurable functions, $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty { x \in [a,b] \mid f(x) > \frac{1}{n} } = [a,b]$, so one of the terms must have positive measure, so $\int_a^b f,dm \ge \frac{1}{n} m(E_n) > 0$.

This is straightforward using the Lebesgue integral, a bit more technical with the Riemann integral. Do you have conditions on $f$ other than, presumably, being Riemann integrable?

@MartinR . yes sir ,know that The integral of a positive function over a non-degenerate interval is always positive.my question is does that mean The integral of a positive function over a non-degenerate interval is zero only if limits are equal ?

@Daun: That is an immediate consequence, isn't it? If the limits are not equal then the integral is positive (or negative, if you allow that $a > b$). Which means that if the integral is zero then then limits must be equal.

@copper.hat.no sir

@MartinR.ok sir Thank you very much. is it also true if f is lebesgue integral too ?

Yes $\int_{[a,b]}f d\lambda =0$ if and only if $f=0$ almost everywhere, since f is positive. That meens [a,b] has to be a null set and is hence a singleton
